# Add a description to a field in Marshmallow

Tags: marshmallow

How can I add a field comment or description in Marshmallow?

I want to show it in something like Apispec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an existing but undocumented feature of APISpec's Marshmallow extension. If your Marhshmallow field has any of the properties in [this list](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/apispec/blob/4e5e761a173cb8de4619ba8b52b97495aa7deb70/apispec/ext/marshmallow/swagger.py#L212), APISpec will use it in the generated Swagger specifications. For example, I have this as one of my schema definitions:

```
class ErrorSchema(Schema):
    code = fields.Int(description="An API specific Error code", required=True)
    message = fields.String(description="A user readable message")
```

which results in APISpec generating the following:

```
ErrorSchema {
message (string, optional): A user readable message,
code (integer): An API specific Error code
}
```